# How do I install with elevated permissions using a WiX installer?

Tags: wix

We currently have an MSI that is created with [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.5. The application is in .NET 3.5. We generate a bootstrapper using the boostrapper task in an [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) file. It's pointing at the 6.0a [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) files.

When users have [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) on and they install, they have to right-click the `setup.exe` and select run-as administrator.

What I would really like is to have the setup.exe automatically prompt to elevate (using that yellow dialog I see in other installs).

Better yet, I'd like the MSI to do this and do away with the `setup.exe` completely, but I think that is what WiX 3.6 is about, right?

If I create the boostrapper using `ApplicationRequiresElevation="true"` this requries the 7.0a SDK, correct? Will the bootstrapper then prompt to elevate automatically? Does this mean the application has to be a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 application? I wouldn't think so...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We've used WiX 3.0 and were able to elevate privileges. However, we didn't elevate our bootstrapper. We elevated the MSI file itself, through the Package property:

```
<Package Id="$(var.PackageCode)"
         Description="$(var.ProductName) $(var.Version)"
         InstallerVersion="301"
         Compressed="yes"
         InstallPrivileges="elevated"  <!-- Elevated right here -->
         InstallScope="perMachine"
         Platform="x86"/>
```

As a side note, our bootstrapper is signed (using signtool.exe from the v6.0A SDK) with our official certificate. I'm not sure if this causes the bootstrapper to also require elevated privileges.

**UPDATE:**

We've got an app.manifest file on our setup.exe bootstrapper project that requires the executable to be run at the administrator level. See the sample below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
                xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
                xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace
            the requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have InstallPrivleges set like this but it doesnt seem to do anything useful.  Running the MSI directly will fail to elevate. Oh, but I just noticed the InstallerVersion is set to 300.  I wonder if that is it....

Comment: @Jonesie: If you don't get a good answer before tomorrow I'll take a closer look at our stuff when I'm at work. I may be able to dig up some more information.

Comment: Cheers mate! I need to run this through our build server which takes an hour so it's rather slow going to try 1 thing at a time :)

Comment: @Jonesie: I just connected remotely to take a look... we have an app.manifest file in our setup.exe project. It has a section for requiring administrator privs on the bootstrapper. See my update.

Comment: Ok, so I found that by removing this property: <!--<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />--> the msi now has a sheild on the install button and I do get the elevation prompt dialog (I think I originally added this to detect if the user was elevated).  However, there is a custom action that is now not working.  This installs a camera driver.  Looking into this...  Thanks again :)

Comment: The custom action had Impersonate=yes.  Removing this fixed the CA and now everything works sweetly.  Cheers

Comment: How can I embed the manifest into the executable?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old topic, but may it save some time to next one.
I had to read all comment, especially `custom action had Impersonate=yes...`

On the other hand Custom Actions have Execute attribute related to privileges:

```
<CustomAction Id = "CA.First"  Execute ="immediate" ... />
<CustomAction Id = "CA.Second" Execute ="deferred"  ... />
```

`CA.First` will be always executed in user mode, but `CA.Second` can have elevated privileges.

May be here are other tricks related to privileges,
main point here - WiX allow control privileges on CustomAction level so make sure you set it right.

[CustomAction Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)