# How-to Admin prompt/elevate/ask for admin rights for .msi installation?

Tags: windows, wix, installation, windows-7-x64, wix3.7

I have got a .msi installer but during the installation I get an error that there are insufficient rights to make a registry change. I guess I need to start .msi as an administrator but there is no UAC prompt coming up to let me grant it admin rights (I am admin on my pc).

I already set `<Package AdminImage="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>`

My setup looks like this: application.exe, batch (candle, light) and application.wxs so there is no visual studio etc.

What ways do I have to get an UAC prompting for admin rights? UAC is already set to the highest level.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled with default settings on the machine where you tested the package? Also, maybe this article will help: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/01/new-wix-feature-setting-package-installation-scope/

Comment: Also, this SO thread contains more useful info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721349/how-do-i-install-with-elevated-permissions-using-a-wix-installer

Comment: Without saying exactly where you are doing this registry change it's tough to know. If you have a custom action writing to the registry in the UI sequence then it is not elevated even if you are admin. The elevation prompt is later than that. If you are using MSI to create the registry entries then they are after the elevation prompt and should work.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with my machine or something similar because on the productive systems the prompt comes up. @PhilDW the changes are in policies of HKCU, hiding changepassword, taskmanager etc.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that if you do those changes with code (custom action) in the UI sequence then you won't be elevated, and those Policies items require elevation to change. Check the UAC settings on your machine maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Execute a command prompt in elevated mode and then call the .MSI from there.