# Wix Installer error: Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: wix

We have a Wix ToolSet Installer (Ver. 3.10).
We try to elevate admin privileges upon a bundle installation, which expands over several projects.

We see examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721349/how-do-i-install-with-elevated-permissions-using-a-wix-installer) which shows how to add an `InstallPrivileges="elevated"` attribute under a `<Package>` node.

We did that already for all projects in the solution.

We keep getting:

> Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due
>   to insufficient permissions

Another way we think may be the solution, is using a pre/post event.

We tried to use a pre/post build events. Something similar to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/28655478/) (we used only the pre build event example) with no avail:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\mt.exe"
>   -manifest "$(ProjectDir)My.manifest" -outputresource:"$(ProjectDir)Setup.exe";

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? It'll be nice to see, how do you read configuration file. If it happens in custom action, then add code that calls that custom action also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to edit a manifest file for the Wix Toolset bootstrapper.

See [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/30317254/) for a direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add the following attributes to the `CustomAction` section:
`Execute="deferred"` and `Impersonate="no"`.

```
<CustomAction Id="MyAction" DllEntry="ActionLibrary" BinaryKey="MethodName" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />
```