# Bootstrapper to check admin rights in a system

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, wix3.6

Is there any possibility  where wix bootstrapper checks whether user has admin privileges so that admin-msi can be installed, if not  a non admin-msi is installed.

basically how to provide install condition inside chain to check windows version and privilege property.

How to make major and minor upgrades for wix bootstrappers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you do not let the Wix bootstrapper "*check whether user has admin privileges*", but  you actually specify the admin rights **for** the Wix installer so it can perform the installation properly.  You would do so by specifying the follow Package properties:

```
     InstallPrivileges="elevated"  
     InstallScope="perMachine"
```

In terms of functionality, this means that a User Access Control window will appear asking the user to allow the Wix installer to proceed with the installation. If the user does not happen to have an administrator account (or an account with administrative rights, however you want to describe it), Windows would require the user to type a username and password of an account that **does** have administrative rights.

Have a look at the following StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721349/how-do-i-install-with-elevated-permissions-using-a-wix-installer).

Hope that helps you!

Comment: what should be the case for a per-user and per-machine installation? My msi should support both installscope.